# Castle ActiveRecord error "Session is closed"

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate, configuration, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to get started with Castle ActiveRecord but I'm stuck trying to make it work in an ASP.NET (MVC, if it matters) application.
In fact I'm getting an ObjectDisposedException during a query with the following message:

> Session is closed!
> Object name: 'ISession'.

I'm initializing ActiveRecord from an XML file (as shown in the getting started) of which the contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<activerecord isWeb="true" isDebug="true" threadinfotype="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Scopes.HybridWebThreadScopeInfo, Castle.ActiveRecord">

  <config>
    <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
    <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" />
    <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
    <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />
    <add key="show_sql" value="true" />
    <add key="default_schema" value="testDB.dbo" />
  </config>

</activerecord>
```

Unfortunately mostly due to lack of documentation and my complete ignorance regarding Castle Windsor I'm not able to find out how should I configure it to make it work, so I'd be thankful if any of you could tell me what's missing or what's wrong.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: I should probably specify that this error occurs on a thread which I spawn in Application_Start and which is in charge of running certain maintenance tasks.

Comment: do you have a nhibernate httpmodule?

Comment: Nope, or if it is so and I haven't realized it's sitting in my /bin, I haven't added any setting for that. Could you please give me more details on the topic? Thanks!

Comment: See http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/Enable+Session+per+Request

Comment: Thanks, but while that's enough for queries being handled during requests, all of my scheduled tasks (running on a separate thread spawned at Application_Start) keep causing the aforementioned exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SessionScope.

In Request___Start, create a new SessionScope() and dispose it in Request_End.

Comment: Could you please add more information or some example code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Your ApplicationStart do something like:

```
void Application_Start(...)  {
    using( SessionScope session = new SessionScope() ) {
        // Your Startup Logic here
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the ActiveRecord stuff is Thread Specific, why not run the ActiveRecord.Initialize(...) again on the new Thread?

Comment: ActiveRecord.Initialize() is not thread specific, it's appdomain-wide