# Session is Closed - Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, exception, castle-activerecord

What is wrong here?

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    using (SessionScope scope = new SessionScope())
    {
        return scope.AsQueryable<Customer>();
    }
}


var result = from x in GetAllCustomers() select x;
Assert.Greater(result.Count(), 0);
```

---

> System.ObjectDisposedException :
>   Session is closed! Object name:
>   'ISession'.

This post didn't help me:
[Castle ActiveRecord error "Session is closed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345249/castle-activerecord-error-session-is-closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the actual query is not being executed in this line:

```
scope.AsQueryable<Customer>();
```

Because you only return an `IQueryable` object that you can query later.

So, it gets executed when you access the data:

```
Assert.Greater(result.Count(), 0);
```

At this point, obviously, the session is already closed (it gets closed when you exit the `using` block).

One of the possible solutions would be to move the `SessionScope` out of the `GetAllCustomers` method:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers(SessionScope scope)
{
    return scope.AsQueryable<Customer>();
}


using (SessionScope scope = new SessionScope())
{
    var result = from x in GetAllCustomers(scope) select x;
    Assert.Greater(result.Count(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlo. Do you know if it is possible to detect when the query is not been used anymore?

Answer (score 3):

The query is actually executed when you run `result.Count()` (LINQ queries are lazily executed), but the SessionScope has already been disposed by then.

If it's a web project, use a [HTTP-request-scoped SessionScope](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/web.html).